# Cant understand what is happening in this compose reduce example in javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming, reduce, composition

```
var user1 = {
  name: 'Nady',
  active: true,
  cart: [],
  purchase: [],
};

var compose = function test1(f, g) {
  return function test2(...args) {
    return f(g(...args));
  };
};

function userPurchase(...fns) {
  return fns.reduce(compose);
}

userPurchase(
  empty,
  addItemToPurchase,
  applayTax,
  addItemToCart
)(user1, { name: 'laptop', price: 876 });


function addItemToCart(user, item) {
  return { ...user, cart: [item] };
}
function applayTax(user) {
  var { cart } = user;
  var taxRate = 1.3;
  var updatedCart = cart.map(function updateCartItem(item) {
    return { ...item, price: item.price * taxRate };
  });

  return { ...user, cart: updatedCart };
}
function addItemToPurchase(user) {
  return { ...user, purchase: user.cart };
}
function empty(user) {
  return { ...user, cart: [] };
}
```

I don't understand this example well. I tried stepping through it with the debugger and concluded the following:

When I call function `userPurchase` the `reduce` will work and at its end `f` will be `test2` and `g` will be `addItemToCart` then `test2` is returned as the accumulated. Then we call it passing `(user1, { name: 'laptop', price: 876 })` as arguments and `g` is called in it that is `addItemToCart`.

I don't understand how `g` is changed to `applayTax`, then `addItemToPurchase`, then `empty` every time function `test2` call itself.

How or why this is happening?

Comment: Don't get too hung up by the variable name `accumulator`. It can be used to implement an accumulator but in this case it is not an accumulator. It is the function `test2`. So `f` is the previous `test2`. In this case `f` does not behave as an accumulator but a composer. Basically this end up constructing `test2(test2(test2(test2 ...`. Remember, `f` is the thing returned by the previous iteration which is `test2`

Comment: Shouldn't g be addItemToCart then applayTax then addItemToPurchase?

Comment: Sorry but I still can't understand why g is changing? After we exit reduce the function test2 will be called; At that moment what g will be? and why it will be changed every time?

Comment: @Muhammad: Please read up on [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).  If a function is returned from the call of another function, it has access to all the values that were in scope, including parameters of the outer function and its local variables.  That is essential to how JS works.

Comment: I love the variety of answers this question has generated!

Comment: Yes @ScottSauyet, every answer is really helpful for me in someway.

Answer (score 2):

The thing that may have gotten you confused is taking the term `accumulator` literally. By convention that's the name of the first argument to a reducer. But it's not necessary to use it to accumulate a value. In this case it is used to compose a series of functions.

The real meaning of the first argument to a reducer is `previouslyReturnedValue`:

```
function compose(previouslyReturnedValue, g) {
  return function (...args) {
    return previouslyReturnedValue(g(...args));
  };
}
```

So let's walk through this loop:

```
[empty, addItemToPurchase, applayTax, addItemToCart].reduce(
    (f,g) => {
        return (...args) => {
            return f(g(...args));
        }
    }
);
```

The first round of the loop, `f = empty` and `g = addItemToPurchase`. This will cause `compose` to return:

```
return (...args) => {
    return empty(addItemToPurchase(...args));
}
```

Leaving the array to become: `[applayTax, addItemToCart]`

The second round of the loop `f = (...args) => {return empty(addItemToPurchase(...args))}` and `g = applyTax`. This will cause `compose` to return:

```
return (...args) => {
    return empty(addItemToPurchase(applyTax(...args)));
}
```

We continue with this logic until we finally get `compose` to return the full chain of functions:

```
return (...args) => {
    return empty(addItemToPurchase(applyTax(addItemToCart(...args))));
}
```

#### Alternate view of the same process

If the above is a bit hard to follow then let's name the anonymous function that becomes `f` in each loop.

In the first round we get:

```
function f1 (...args) {
    return empty(addItemToPurchase(...args));
}
```

In the second round we get:

```
function f2 (...args) {
    return f1(applyTax(...args));
}
```

In the final round we get:

```
function f3 (...args) {
    return f2(addItemToCart(...args));
}
```

It is this function `f3` that is returned by `reduce()`. So when you call the return value of reduce it will try to do:

```
f2(addItemToCart(...args))
```

Which will call `addItemToCart()` and then call `f2` which will execute:

```
f1(applyTax(...args))
```

Which will call `applyTax()` and then call `f1` which will execute:

```
empty(addItemToPurchase(...args))
```

Which will call `addItemToPurchase()` and then call `empty()`

#### TLDR

Basically all this is doing:

```
let tmp;

tmp = addItemToCart(args);
tmp = applyTax(tmp);
tmp = addItemToPurchase(tmp);
tmp = empty(tmp);
```

#### More readable version

There is a way to implement this logic which is more readable and easier to understand if we abandon `reduce()`. I personally like the functional array methods like `map()` and `reduce()` but this is one of those rare situations where a regular `for` loop may lead to much more readable and debuggable code. Here's a simple alternative implementation that does exactly the same thing:

```
function userPurchase(...fns) {
  return function(...args) {
    let result = args;

    // The original logic apply the functions in reverse:
    for (let i=fns.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        let f = fns[i];
        result = f(result);
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Personally I find the implementation of `userPurchase` using a `for` loop much more readable than the `reduce` version. It clearly loops through the functions in reverse order and keep calling the next function with the result of the previous function.

Comment: `function compose(previouslyReturnedValue, g) { return function (...args) {return previouslyReturnedValue(g(...args));};}`
Okay now i understand what is going wrong in my mind.
we say `f` is the `previouslyReturnedValue` so it should be:
`ƒ anonymous (...args) { return f(g(...args)); }`
until we execute it then it will define f and g and finds g with its last value  `addItemToCart()` and f will be the same.
I mean `empty(addItemToPurchase(applyTax(...args)));`  is the return of the return not the return itself.
why we use it as the return ?

Comment: Because that's how functional loop functions like `map` and `reduce` work. Each round of the loop needs to return a result, not just the last round. Personally I'd rewrite the code to look like my **TLDR** explanation because that's easier to read unless you really need to do some metaprogramming - for example if you need to let your user configure what functions need to be called in what order - let's say when you're creating your own GUI configurable CMS. Otherwise all this complexity feels unnecessary to me

Comment: @MuhammadHossam Wait.. I have an idea to make the dynamic code much easier to read. Let me add something to my answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. the for loop is much better.
But i can't understand the meaning of each loop needs to return a result.why the function is not a result?
should it work in this example ?
`var x = [1, 2, 3].reduce(function test1(acc, curr) { return function test2() { return acc + curr; };});
console.log(x);`

Comment: `curr` is a function. You cannot use `+` operator with a function. You need to do `curr(args)`. And as I mentioned. It is not attempting to do an addition or merge operation (accumulation). It is attempting to construct nested function calls `f3(f2(f1(g(args))))`

Comment: Notice that even in the for loop we do not use `+` operator to process the results. Instead we do `result = f(result)` repeatedly

Comment: Note that the reduce is not trying to add/accumulate the result. Instead it is doing very different operations in sequence: add item to cart then apply tax then add item to purchase then empty cart. There is no way to use the `+` operator to achieve them. Say for example the item cost $1. You cannot do `1 + 1` to apply tax. You also cannot use `+` with `1` in any way to add the `1` to the shopping cart (which I assume is an array). So the first thing the reduced sequence of functions do is to `push()` the `1` into an array which cannot be achieved using `+` in any way.

Comment: ... the second thing it does is calculate tax percentage and add it to the price which maybe can be implemented with `+` if used creatively but not just a direct use of `+`. And so on

Comment: Oh okay i thought it would read `curr` as a number to just get a result anyway. Also the idea of using `+` to add the tax to the price is a great idea, i will try to implement this idea.

Comment: it's more clear to me now Slebetman.Thank you so much for your great help,and to be patient with me so i can understand.  I really appreciate your great help and answer.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help at all?

```js
var user1 = {
  name: 'Nady',
  active: true,
  cart: [],
  purchase: [],
};

function compose(f, g) {
  const composition = function(...args) {
    console.log('f name', f.name);
    console.log('g name', g.name);
    return f(g(...args));
  };
  Object.defineProperty(composition, 'name', {
    value: 'composition_of_' + f.name + '_and_' + g.name,
    writable: false
  });
  return composition;
};

function userPurchase(...fns) {
  return fns.reduce(compose);
}

function addItemToCart(user, item) {
  return { ...user, cart: [item] };
}

function applayTax(user) {
  var { cart } = user;
  var taxRate = 1.3;
  var updatedCart = cart.map(function updateCartItem(item) {
    return { ...item, price: item.price * taxRate };
  });

  return { ...user, cart: updatedCart };
}
function addItemToPurchase(user) {
  return { ...user, purchase: user.cart };
}
function empty(user) {
  return { ...user, cart: [] };
}

const result = userPurchase(
  empty,
  addItemToPurchase,
  applayTax,
  addItemToCart
)(user1, { name: 'laptop', price: 876 });

console.log(result);
```

Let's say you need to take in a number, add ten to it and then double it. You could write some functions like:

```
const add_ten = function(num) { return num + 10; };
const double = function(num) { return num * 2; };

const add_ten_and_double = function(num) { return double(add_ten(num)); };
```

You could also write the same thing as:

```js
function compose(outer_function, inner_function) {
  return function(num) {
    return outer_function(inner_function(num));
  };
};

const add_ten = function(num) { return num + 10; };
const double = function(num) { return num * 2; };

const add_ten_and_double = compose(double, add_ten);

console.log('typeof add_ten_and_double:', typeof add_ten_and_double);
console.log('add_ten_and_double:', add_ten_and_double(4));
```

Using compose, we've created a function that does the same thing as our original add_ten_and_double function. Does that make sense up to here? (Point A).

If we then decided to add five we could have:

```js
function compose(outer_function, inner_function) {
  return function(num) {
    return outer_function(inner_function(num));
  };
};

const add_ten = function(num) { return num + 10; };
const double = function(num) { return num * 2; };
const add_five = function(num) { return num + 5; };

const add_ten_and_double_and_add_five = compose(compose(add_five, double), add_ten);

console.log('typeof add_ten_and_double_and_add_five :', typeof add_ten_and_double_and_add_five);
console.log('add_ten_and_double_and_add_five :', add_ten_and_double_and_add_five(4));
```

Now we've run compose using a function and a function that was composed of two other functions, but what we've got back is still just a function that takes a number and returns a number. Does that make sense up to here? (Point B).

If we wanted to add a few more functions then we would end up with a lot of compose calls in our code, so we could just say "give me the composition of all of these functions", and it might look like:

```js
function compose(outer_function, inner_function) {
  return function(num) {
    return outer_function(inner_function(num));
  };
};

const add_ten = function(num) { return num + 10; };
const double = function(num) { return num * 2; };
const add_five = function(num) { return num + 5; };

functions_to_compose = [add_five, double, add_ten];

let composition;
functions_to_compose.forEach(function(to_compose) {
  if(!composition)
    composition = to_compose;
  else
    composition = compose(composition, to_compose);
});

const add_ten_and_double_and_add_five = composition;

console.log('typeof add_ten_and_double_and_add_five:', typeof add_ten_and_double_and_add_five);
console.log('add_ten_and_double_and_add_five:', add_ten_and_double_and_add_five(4));
```

The fns.reduce(compose); in userPurchase in your code is basically doing the same thing as the forEach loop here, but neater. Does that make sense why add_ten_and_double_and_add_five is a function that you can pass in a number and all of the operations from functions_to_compose are being applied (last to first) to the number? (Point C).

Comment: if you please can help me more inside reduce. in my mind first `f` will be `empty` `g` will be `addItemToPurchase`. After that the accumulated will be the returned value (my problem starts from here)  the returned value will be `function test2(...args) {return f(g(...args)); };` (not `f(g(...args))`) then second iteration accumulation will be the same because the returned value will be the same what is changing is the current value only.
then what is returned is executed that is `function test2` inside it `f` will be `test2` and `g` will be the last change that happened to it.
why this wrong

Comment: I'm not sure I can do a better job of desribing what's going on in detail in reduce than @slebetman has already done; sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks ben for your great help. I appreciate your great answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Renaming

Part of the problem is simply in naming.  It would help to introduce one more function, and to rename two others.

```js
var composeTwo = function test1(f, g) {
  return function test2(...args) {
    return f(g(...args));
  };
};

function composeMany(...fns) {
  return fns.reduce(composeTwo);
}

const userPurchase = composeMany(
  empty,
  addItemToPurchase,
  applyTax,
  addItemToCart
) 

userPurchase(user1, { name: 'laptop', price: 876 });
//=> {active: true, cart: [], name: "Nady", purchase: [{name: "laptop", price: 1138.8}]}

// other functions elided
```

**`composeTwo`** (originally called `compose`) is a function that accepts two functions and returns a new one which accepts some input, calls the second function with that input and then calls the first function with the result.  This is straightforward mathematical composition of functions.

**`composeMany`** (which as originally called -- very confusingly -- `userPurchase`) extends this composition to work on a list of functions, using `reduce` to sequentially call each function on the result of the pipeline so far, starting with the arguments passed.  Note that it works from the last item in the list to the first one.

We use this to define the new **`userPurchase`**, which passes `empty`, `addItemToPurchase`, `applyTax` and `addItemToCart` to `pipeline`.  This returns a *function* that will then apply them in sequence, doing something equivalent to `function (...args) {return empty1(addItemToPurchase(applyTax(addItemToCart(...args))))}`

We can see this in action in this snippet:

```js
var user1 = {
  name: 'Nady',
  active: true,
  cart: [],
  purchase: [],
};

var composeTwo = function test1(f, g) {
  return function test2(...args) {
    return f(g(...args));
  };
};

function composeMany (...fns) {
  return fns.reduce(composeTwo);
}

const userPurchase = composeMany (
  empty,
  addItemToPurchase,
  applyTax,
  addItemToCart
) 

console .log (
  userPurchase(user1, { name: 'laptop', price: 876 })
)


function addItemToCart(user, item) {
  return { ...user, cart: [item] };
}
function applyTax(user) {
  var { cart } = user;
  var taxRate = 1.3;
  var updatedCart = cart.map(function updateCartItem(item) {
    return { ...item, price: item.price * taxRate };
  });

  return { ...user, cart: updatedCart };
}
function addItemToPurchase(user) {
  return { ...user, purchase: user.cart };
}
function empty(user) {
  return { ...user, cart: [] };
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

### Modern Syntax

However, I would find this much cleaner with a more modern JS syntax.  This is very much equivalent, but cleaner:

```js
const composeTwo = (f, g)  => (...args)  => 
  f (g (...args))

const composeMany = (...fns) =>
  fns .reduce (composeTwo)

// .. other functions elided

const userPurchase = composeMany (
  empty,
  addItemToPurchase,
  applyTax,
  addItemToCart
)
```

Here it should be obvious that `composeTwo` takes two functions and returns a function.  And in knowing that and understanding `.reduce`, it should be clear that `composeMany` takes a list of functions and returns a new function.  This version, which also applies this change to the remaining functions is available in this snippet:

```js
var composeTwo = (f, g)  => (...args)  => 
  f (g (...args))

const composeMany = (...fns) =>
  fns .reduce (composeTwo)

const addItemToCart = (user, item) =>
  ({ ...user, cart: [item] })

const applyTax = (user)  => {
  var { cart } = user;
  var taxRate = 1.3;
  var updatedCart = cart .map (item => ({ ...item, price: item .price * taxRate }))
  return { ...user, cart: updatedCart };
}

const addItemToPurchase = (user) =>
  ({ ...user, purchase: user.cart })

const empty = (user) =>
  ({ ...user, cart: [] })


const userPurchase = composeMany (
  empty,
  addItemToPurchase,
  applyTax,
  addItemToCart
)

const user1 = {
  name: 'Nady',
  active: true,
  cart: [],
  purchase: [],
};

console .log (
  userPurchase (user1, { name: 'laptop', price: 876 })
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

### How `reduce` and `composeTwo` work together

Here we try to demonstrate how `reduce` works with `composeTwo` to compose multiple functions into one.

In the first step, the `init` parameter to `reduce` is missing, so JS uses the first value in the array as the initial one, and starts iterating with the second one.  So `reduce` first calls `composeTwo` with `empty` and `addItemToPurchase`, yielding a function equivalent to

```js
(...args) => empty (addItemsToPurchase (...args))
```

Now `reduce` passes that function and `applyTax` to `compose`, yielding a function like

```js
(...args) => ((...args2) => empty (addItemsToPurchase (...args2))) (applyTax (...args))
```

Now this is structured like the following:

```js
(x) => ((y) => f ( g (y)) (h (x))
```

where `x` represents `...args`, `y` represents `...args2`, `f` represents `empty`, `g` represents `addItems`, and `h` represents `applyTax`.

but the right-hand side is a function (`(y) => f ( g ( y))`) with the value `h (x)` applied to it.  This is the same as replacing `y` in the body with `h(x)`, yielding `f (g (h (x)))`, so that this function is equivalent to  `(x) => f (g (h (x)))`, and by replacing our original values, this ends up as

```js
(...args) => empty (addItemsToPurchase (applyTax ( ...args)))
```

Do note that this application of values to the function does not happen now when the function is being built.  It will happen when the resulting function is called.  In memory, this is still something like `(...args) => ((...args2) => empty (addItems (...args2))) (applyTax (...args))`.  But this logical version shows how it will work.

Of course we now do it again for `addItemToCart`:

```js
(...args) => ((...args2) => empty (addItemsToPurchase (applyTax ( ...args2)))) (addItemToCart (...args))
```

and by the same sort of application, we get the equivalent of

```js
(...args) => empty (addItems (applyTax ( addItemToCart (...args))))
```

Which is the basic definition of the composition of those functions.

### Cleaning up the tax rate

There's something strange about the hard-coded tax rate.  We can fix that by making a parameter used in calling `userPurchase`.  This also allows us to clean up the `applyTax` function:

```js
const applyTax = (taxRate) => ({cart, ...rest}) => ({
  ... rest,
  cart: cart .map (item => ({ ...item, price: item .price * taxRate }))
})

const userPurchase = (taxRate) => composeMany (
  empty,
  addItemToPurchase,
  applyTax(taxRate),
  addItemToCart
)

// ...

userPurchase (1.3) (user1, { name: 'laptop', price: 876 })
```

Note that the curried nature of this parameter lets us choose to apply just this value to get back a tax-rate specific function:

```js
const someDistrictPurchase = userPurchase (1.12) // 12% tax

someDistrictPurchase(user, item)
```

Which we can see in one more snippet:

```js
var composeTwo = (f, g)  => (...args)  => 
  f (g (...args))

const composeMany = (...fns) =>
  fns .reduce (composeTwo)

const addItemToCart = (user, item) =>
  ({ ...user, cart: [item] })

const applyTax = (taxRate) => ({cart, ...rest}) => ({
  ... rest,
  cart: cart .map (item => ({ ...item, price: item .price * taxRate }))
})

const addItemToPurchase = (user) =>
  ({ ...user, purchase: user.cart })

const empty = (user) =>
  ({ ...user, cart: [] })

const userPurchase = (taxRate) => composeMany (
  empty,
  addItemToPurchase,
  applyTax(taxRate),
  addItemToCart
)

var user1 = { name: 'Nady', active: true, cart: [], purchase: []}

console .log (
  userPurchase (1.3) (user1, { name: 'laptop', price: 876 })
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

### Lessons

- Function composition is an essential part of functional programming (FP).  While it    helps to have functions like `composeTwo` and `composeMany`, it is much better if they have understandable names.  (Note that `compose` is a perfectly legitimate name for the first one.  My change here was just to make the distinction with `composeMany` clearer.)  The biggest problem, to my mind was the original name of `userPurchase` as a composition function.  That confuses a lot of things.
- Modern JS (arrow functions, rest/spread, and destructuring) makes for code that is not only more succinct but generally easier to understand.

Comment: if you please can help me more inside reduce. in my mind first `f` will be `empty`,`g` will be `addItemToPurchase`.After that the accumulated will be the returned value (my problem starts from here) the returned value will be `function test2(...args) {return f(g(...args)); }`; (not `f(g(...args))`) then second iteration accumulation will be the same because the returned value will be the same what is changing is the current value only. then what is returned is executed that is function `test2` inside it `f` will be `test2` and `g` will be the last change that happened to it. why this wrong

Comment: @Muhammad: I added a section trying to explain that more fully.  I used my modern JS versions of these functions, as they are much easier to work with for this sort of description, but the same principle applies to the original versions.

Comment: So functions in javascript knowing every variable inside it referring to what exactly,even before it is executed?I read many articles saying that there are two phases when the function is executed, compilation phase and execution phase. In the compilation phase the engine will see every variable in the function and assign variables defined with var to undefined(hoisting) but here the function`test2`entered the compilation phase and know every variable refer to what (like `f` is `empty`) even before we execute it. I conclude that compilation phase happened even if we didnt execute the function?

Comment: @Muhammad: I'm afraid I don't understand most of your question.  You might want to read up on [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). But to the concluding query, yes, the compilation phase happens with or without execution.

Comment: Thanks Scott  for your great help, its more clear for me now. I think my problem was to understand that the function knows what inside it even before it get executed so i thought at the end `f` will be `test2` and when it get executed it will call itself and there will be something like an infinite loop.